# how to repeat a vxworks 6.9 shell command in the shell interpreter

Tags: vxworks

Is there a single key to step through past vxworks v6.9 shell interpreter commands, like  for Windows and Linux?

'h' shows a list of command history.

How can I step through this and select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses the VI key bindings by default.

```
esc-K  - go back in history
esc-J  - go forward in history
```